# cups-insecure-filter error for Lexmark printer on Trusty

Tags: printing, lexmark, cups-lpd

I am trying to install my Lexmark S800 Series printer (32-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty, and I continue to get a `cups-insecure-filter` error message.  The printer is connected to LPT1, and the printer wizard correctly adds the Printer/PPD.  It's when I first go to print a test page that I get the error.

I followed the instructions on [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082570) to ensure that the permissions were correct for `/usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter`.

Has anyone else had this issue trying to get a Lexmark printer running on Trusty?  No amount of googling has helped on this one.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

This is probably too late to help the original poster, but for others searching some day:

```
sudo chmod g-w /usr/local/lexmark/v3/etc/lxS800.ppd
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

For other models of Lexmark printers, choose the appropriate .ppd file in
/usr/local/lexmark/v3/etc

Answer (score 2):

I have an Epson WF-3520 and was getting the `cups-insecure-filter` error.

I've solved it by setting the owner of the Epson source directory to `root`:

```
sudo chown root:root -R /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201212w/
```

It's installed on `/opt` directory, which I've also changed to owner `root`. I don't know if this is relevant.

After that I was getting following error in the log `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
```

I solved it by recovering some permissions that I had previously changed on some tests:

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-201212w/cups/lib/filter/epson_inkjet_printer_filter
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error with my Epson Workforce 840 on 16.04 because root was not the owner of `/opt/epson-inkjet-printer-workforce-840-series`.

This was fixed by changing the ownership to root with:

```
sudo chown -R root /opt/epson-inkjet-printer-workforce-840-series
```

followed by restarting cups with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

Finally, and this part may or may not have been necessary, I also deleted and re-added the printer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was with file /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter as in the original question, same solution above applied to this file solved the problem for me:

```
sudo chmod g-w /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/printfilter
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
```

This is rather simpler as the page linked in the original question.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?61633-Cups-insecure-filter-Lexmark-Prospect-Pro205-and-scanning-issues
this worked for me:

`sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/*`

`sudo chown root:bin /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/*`

Comment: I 've got problems with a Brother printer.  After setting the owner and permissions on the installation directory (which was /opt/printers/brother/...... to root:root and 755 my problem was gone.
Thanks to you all, quick and clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (ubuntu 16.04.1 - lexmark S405):

```
cd /usr/local/lexmark/v3/bin/
sudo chmod 755 printfilter
```

I take from this [Ubuntu forum tread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082570)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of about file permissions on the internet. They couldn't solve the insecure permissions issue.

My original driver is located on /opt/brother/..... and there is a symbolic link on /usr/lib/cups/filter..
permission was

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     68 Eyl 28 05:37 brother_lpdwrapper_HL1210W
```

original file permissions was

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5139 Eyl 16  2014 /opt/brother/Printers/HL1210W/cupswrapper/brother_lpdwrapper_HL1210W
```

I removed symbolic link and move file to /usr/lib/cups/filter/

and it solved my issue...